# The problem is got executed but it doesn't calculate the netpay

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Employee{
    public String Staffname;
    public int StaffID;
    public int BasicSalary;
    public int Allowances;  
    public void Staff()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Staff name=");
        this.Staffname=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the Staff ID=");
        this.StaffID=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the Basic Salary");
        this.BasicSalary=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the Allowances");
        this.Allowances=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("***Employee Details Registered Successfully***");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
class Marketing extends Employee{
    public int sales_incentives;
    public int net_pay;
    public void Staff()
    {
        System.out.println(super.BasicSalary);
        System.out.println(super.Allowances);
        this.net_pay=super.BasicSalary+super.Allowances+this.sales_incentives;
        System.out.println("Net pay="+net_pay);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Marketing m=new Marketing();
        Employee e=new Employee();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        e.Staff();
        System.out.println("Enter the incentives=");
        m.sales_incentives= sc.nextInt();
        m.Staff();
        
    }
}
```

This is a program for overriding method.The program got Executed but isnt calculating the netpay.[The output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYRCK.jpg) How to call the Basic salary and allowance from the super to calculate the Net pay. Can't able to find the mistake.

Comment: Please think about starting your attribute and method declarations with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the super method, just do it this way:

```
public void Staff()
{
    super.Staff();

    System.out.println(super.BasicSalary);
    System.out.println(super.Allowances);
    this.net_pay=super.BasicSalary+super.Allowances+this.sales_incentives;
    System.out.println("Net pay="+net_pay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `m` object did not run `Employee::Staff()`, so `BasicSalary` and `Allowances` are undefined.

Add `super.Staff()` to the top of `Marketing::Staff()` method. Better yet, move the incentive query into that method, too, so your abstraction doesn't leak into `main()`.